# JQuery Error using plugin in custom theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am having some issues implementing a plugin into my custom theme.

I keep getting the following exception:

`Uncaught TypeError: $node.addClass(...).block is not a function`

However the plugin works fine with the default wordpress themes - i.e. twentyfifteen

I am not too sure where to look in my theme to address this problem, I have tried updating to a more recent version of jquery but didn't get any luck.

Current jquery version on my custom theme is 1.11.3

Just looking for some guesses what in my custom theme would cause this error?

Comment: FYI the plugin is Local Pickup Plus

Comment: Is this error coming for hte plugin or from your custom theme? You are supposed to see the line number in which file that error occured. When you found it, post the code block where this line is.

Comment: `block = function($node) {
      if ($node && !is_blocked($node)) {
        return $node.addClass('processing').block({
          message: null,
          overlayCSS: {
            background: '#fff',
            opacity: 0.6
          }
        });
      }
    };`

Comment: error occurs at all instance where it calls the `$node.addClass('processing').block({` and performs the .addClass action

Comment: Error is in the plugin code - but only when running in my custom theme, so I think it must be something to do with a conflict with jquery?

Comment: The error, for sure, isn't due to `.addClass()`. The error says that `block` is not a function. Else, it would say `$node.addClass is not a function`.

Comment: Ha-Haa! I found what this `block` function is... [Click here](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element). That is a plugin your custom theme probably doesn't include... But that is a dependency of the "Local Pickup Plus" plugin.

Comment: hmm interesting - I ended up getting it working it seems like the previous developer that started the custom theme was loading in Jquery in the footer of the site when combined with the WP jquery it was causing conflicts. By removing that tag and then cleaning up code that required the footer jquery I seem to have a working solution. but I am still bug testing. thank you for your help :)